# How does this theorem imply unique linear functionals comprising dual basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, dual-spaces

Let $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ be a basis for $V$ and $\phi_1,...,\phi_n$ be a basis for $V^*$. A couple of linear algebra texts (Axler and Kunze/Hoffman) introduce the dual basis and say that the fact that "there is for each $i$ a unique linear functional $\phi_i$ on $V$ such that $\phi_i(\alpha_j) = \delta_{i,j}$" is implied by the theorem below (from Axler's "Linear Algebra").

[image]

I don't understand how the theorem in the image above implies the theorem in quotes. One reason that I don't understand how it follows is because the way that I would apply the theorem in the image is:

If $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ is a basis for $V$ and $\phi_1,...,\phi_n$ is a basis for $V^*$, then exists a unique $T$ such that $T\alpha_i = \phi_i$.

However, this application of the theorem does not match the form of the quoted theorem. If instead of applying the theorem in the image to every basis vector of $V$ simultaneously, I instead apply it to each basis vector $\alpha_i$, then I would let $\alpha_i$, $F$, and $\phi_i$ take the place of $V$, $W$, and $T$ in the image, respectively. Then I would have that $\phi_i(\alpha_i) = 1$.
Is this how the theorem in the image is being applied to imply the quoted theorem? If so, does the theorem in the image also imply that $\phi_i(\alpha_j) = 0$ when $i \neq j$? Or does that property only follow from the definition of the dual basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Theorem 3.5 you are quoting is often used in the case where the $w_i$ form a basis, but that is not a hypothesis of the theorem and indeed the theorem is true for *any* choice of $w_i$.

In your case you can take $W = F$ (the field as a $1$-dimensional vector space) and $w_j = \delta_{ij}$.  This means your linear functional is defined by $\phi_i(\alpha_i) = 1$ and $\phi_i(\alpha_j) = 0$ whenever $j \neq i$.

So in a sense, the condition $\phi_i(\alpha_j) = 0$ when $i \neq j$ does follow from the theorem and also follows from the definition of the dual basis.  The theorem tells you that you can define a linear map by picking out the images of the basis elements.  The definition of the dual basis is that for $\phi_i$ we choose $\delta_{ij}$ as the image of $\alpha_j$.  The theorem says you can choose anything you want, the definition tells you the name we've given to one particular choice you could have made.

Comment: The last piece that I'm not getting is why you can let $w = \delta_{ij}$ which implies that your selection of $w_j$ places restraints on the outputs of $Tv_i$ for $i \neq j$ when Theorem 3.5 places no such restraints on values of  $Tv_i$. Also, Theorem 3.5 says there exists a unique (i.e. single) linear map, $T$, but in the dual basis definition we use multiple maps, {$\phi_1,..., \phi_n$}. Unless the key is that we're thinking of $\phi_i$ as being 1 single/unique linear map and the $w = \delta_{ij}$ as also being a single value). These are subtle points but important and I'm at a loss.

Comment: The dual basis contains $n$ linear maps, $\phi_1, \ldots, \phi_n$.  Each linear map $\phi_i$ is defined using the theorem, so you're using the theorem $n$ times, not just $1$ time.  As for "restraints on the outputs" I don't understand what you mean.  The theorem says you can pick the $w_j$ to be anything, I'm just telling you what to pick.  When you define $\phi_i$ you pick $w_j = \delta_{ij}$.  If you want to pick something else and define a *different* map go ahead, but those maps will be different than the ones in the dual basis.

Comment: Thanks! The theorem being used $n$ times clears up one point. But it's still unclear to me why one is **allowed** to pick $\delta_{ij}$ as $w$. In Theorem 3.5, $Tv_i$ defines $w_i$, but it does not define $w_j$ for $i \neq j$. Yet in the dual basis, $\phi_{i}v_j$ does define $w_j$ for $i \neq j$, it defines it as 0. Why are we allowed to do this when the map in Theorem 3.5 does not? Is it because we are really picking $w=\delta_{ij}$ to begin with and Theorem 3.5 is telling us that whatever we pick, there will exist unique maps $\phi_i$ that make  $\phi_{i}v_j=\delta_{ij}$ possible?

Comment: The theorem says that to define $T$ you pick the image of each basis element, so you are choosing the image of both $v_i$ and $v_j$.  To define $\phi_i$ using the theorem we choose the image of each basis element.  So we choose the image of $v_i$ and of $v_j$ for $j \neq i$.  In both cases we are making one choice per basis element.

Comment: That makes total sense now. Each time you apply Theorem 3.5 you are choosing $n$ mappings. Since you are applying this theorem $n$ times in the definition of the dual basis, you are choosing a total of $n^2$ mappings, but for each dual basis map, say $\phi_1$ you still choose $n$ mappings (one for each $v_j$ for $j  = 1, ..., n$) which is why using $w = \delta_{1j}$ in this case where $i = 1$ is totally legitimate (since it defines $n$ mappings which is what we need each time we apply Theorem 3.5). Thanks Jim!